# How to get actual DOM CSS width on hover?

Tags: css, hover, google-chrome-devtools

How can I expand to see the computed width when I have to mouse over to make the event happen? Whenever I mouse over a link in my menu the width gets changed from 270 pixels to 850 pixels and throws the entire menu out of whack.

But I can't determine what CSS style element is causing this shift, because I have to hold the mouse over the link, and there's no way to expand the computed style to see what is causing this.

I tried using the tab and arrow keys thinking that would cycle me through Chrome's UI elements, but no luck. Any ideas?

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

BTW: the menu is created by a 3rd party tool that I have wrapped in asp.net. Here's the created element that is being affected:

```
<td emtype="c" colspan="2" class="ParentItemContentCell"><a href="/Admin/Default.aspx?p=9">Admin Home</a></td>
```

And here's the CSS code, in case you care to see it:

```
.ParentItemContentCell
{
        width:100%;
    font: 12px Tahoma; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ParentItemContentCellOver
{
    font: 12px Tahoma; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #361A53;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%;
}

.ParentItemContentCellOver a
{
    font: 12px Tahoma; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #361A53;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: By right-clicking an element in the inspector html view, you can force a state change(:active, :hover, etc).  You can then use this to debug further.  Also, without seeing more html, or a link to your page, a good chunk of us are going to have a hard time debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

[there are two answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:158449%20%5Bgoogle-chrome-devtools%5D%20is:answer)

hover checkbox in styles pane

[image: hover checkbox in styles]

and element state context menu

[image: and element state context menu]